# How can I swipe/scroll horizontally with acceleration/deceleration through a set of images in a DIV on a mobile site using only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to allow mobile site users to swipe/scroll through a list of icons.

The icons are `div` tags containing `img` tags.

[image]

The user should be able to swipe the container, scrolling/sliding the elements left or right.

The images need to slide smoothly with acceleration and deceleration.

Needs to work on iOS and Android.

Comment: For iOS smooth scrolling use -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; on the container

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We needed something like this sometime back, so I made a demo for it at that time. It's pretty basic, but it'll lay up all the ground work you need. First, lets start with the markup :

### Markup

Since you mentioned jQM in the tag section of your question, Im gonna go with jQM `[data-role=page]` markup. You'd have a structure like this :

```
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1>Slideshow</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <div class="images">
        <!--your images here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So you'd put all your images in the div with `class=images`. A particular group of images were encapsulated within `a` tags like this :

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="25AC.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="#"> 
  <img src="nature.jpg" />
</a>
<!--so on-->
```

You'd place this inside `div.images`. So that's about the markup we have.

### CSS

The stylesheet part is simple.

```
.images {
    height : 280px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color : #272722;

}
.images a{
  padding : 14px 5px 0px 5px;
  margin: 5px 3px 0px 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

images img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height:512px;
}
```

**Important properties to note here :**

1. **The `overflow-x`, `overflow-y` properties** : The former needs to be enabled and the latter needs to be disabled. Only then the scroll will happen when you swipe right or left.
2. **The `white-space` property** : This is important to make the images come in a straight horizontal layout.
3. **The `max-width` property** : This is for scaling the images on mobile.

That's it! You're done!

### Extras

I just added a popup to show the image when its tapped so that I'd be able to demonstrate the event handling. Here's the popup :

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="b" data-corners="false">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <div id="stuff"></div>
</div>
```

I'd be putting the image inside `div#stuff` when the `a` surrounding the `img` is clicked. Here's the JS :

```
//pageinit event of page
$(document).on("pageinit", "[data-role=page]", function() {
  //cache popup for future use
  var $popup = $("#popupInfo");
  //click event for "a" tag inside .images
  $(this).on("click", ".images > a[href=#]", function(e) {
    //prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();
    //clone the image inside "a"
    var $img = $(this).find("img").clone();
    //add the cloned image inside #stuff
    $popup.find("#stuff").html($img);
    //open popup()
    $popup.popup().popup("open");
  });
});
```

### Demo & Code

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/abocok/1) & [Code](http://jsbin.com/abocok/1/edit) at jsbin.com

### Alternatives

You could try out swipejs, which is jQuery plugin which will provide a much more sophisticated functionality. [Here's the link to the site.](http://swipejs.com/)